# jQuery Autocomplete in ESRI Javascript API: Array Shows Duplicate Values

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, dojo, esri

I have a dynamically built form in ESRI/Dojo javascript API. But that shouldn't matter because jQuery should be able to do the job. In my code below, when the autocomplete works, I see selections not only which are multiple (duplicates) but also are not in rows but duplicates are in one line, such such in the attached image.

[image: My Output]

Something wrong in my code, obviously.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```js
   

 $(myInput).keyup(function (arg_Input) {
     //query to get values of the PROBLEM field
      var QueryTask = new queryTask(_workOrderFeatureLayer.url);
      var queryParams = new Query();
     queryParams.where = "PROBLEM LIKE '" + arg_Input.target.value+ "%'" ;
     queryParams.returnGeometry = false;
     queryParams.outFields = ["PROBLEM"];
     problem_values = [];//cleanup. **Update: Removes Duplicate Problem**
     QueryTask.execute(queryParams, function (results) {
     dojo.forEach(results.features, function (value, index) {                                                    
      problem_values.push(value.attributes.PROBLEM);                                               
      });
      },
      lang.hitch(myWidget, 'errorResults')
    );
    $(myInput).autocomplete({
    source: problem_values,
    minLength: 3
    });
 }
                                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It was apparently some conflict with CSS. I fixed by making a fixed width for the UI component:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
 width: 200px !important;
}
```

Not a great solution because the values could be much longer or shorter. If very short values then will include two in a row. If very long values then they will wrap around. I guess will have to play with the width values if needed.

HTH.

Thanks.